# Create stack class without System.Collections

Tags: c#, stack

Anyone knows how to create stack class in C# for doing tasks such as push, pop, peek and find without using the "System.Collections"?

Comment: Why no love for System.Collections?

Comment: @Jay Riggs: Something tells me this is a homework question and he was forbidden from using `System.Collections` because that would **defeat the point.**

Comment: I am just experimenting to learn alternative approaches.

Comment: Interview question :), added answer below...

Answer (score 4):

Make a linked list and add/remove the tail?

Seriously, if you understand how a stack works you *should* be able to make one fairly easily.

- [Here is a Wikipedia Article Explaining how linked lists work.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)
- [Here is a Wikipedia Article Explaining how stacks work.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29)

I don't mean to be crass but the way you phrased your question makes it sound like you know what a stack is, and just don't want to simply write it yourself.

A linked list would be faster than an array, just keep a back-reference on your linked list nodes and hold not only the head, but the tail in the Stack Class yourself, and you'll save tonnes of cycles on the tail discovery and on add/remove time.

**Edit:**

*If this is homework, you may get bonus marks for efficiency, if it's not; you'll just have a fast stack :p*

Comment: Huh? For an array you just keep an index to the top of the stack. Where are the wasted cycles?

Comment: Increasing Size, if the stack exceeds the size of the array, you have to re-allocate a larger one, and copy the values from the old to new. The problems with arrays: expansion, The problems with linked list: Discovery Time. I offered a solution that eliminated both approaches drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Node
{
    Node next;
    Object data;
}

class Stack {

  Node Top;

  public Node Pop()
  {
    if(Top==null)
       return null;

    Node n = Top;
    Top = Top.Next;
    return n;
  }

  public void Push(Object i)
  {
    Node n = new Node(i);
    n.Next = Top;
    Top = n;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a linked list:

```
public class Item
{
   public Item next {get; set;}
   public Item previous {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a stack by wrapping an array with implementations of push/pop/peek. This is standard first course in data structures fodder.

Alternatively, build your own linked list implementation and then wrap it with implementations of push/pop/peek.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, You can create a Stack program without any collection.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace DataStructures
{
    class Stack
    {
        Object[] stack;
        Int32 i;
        Int32 j;

       public Stack(int n)
        {
            stack = new Object[n];
            i = 0;
            j = n;
        }

        public void Push(object item)
        {
            if (!isStackFull())
            {
                stack[i++] = item;
            }
            else
            Console.WriteLine("Stack is Full");
        }

        public bool isStackFull()
        {
            if (i == j)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public object Pop()
        {
            if (stack.Length != 0)
                return stack[--i];
            return -1;
            Console.WriteLine("Stack is empty");
        }

        public object TopElement()
        {
            if (stack.Length != 0)
                return stack[i - 1];
            return 0;
        }
    }

}

  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stack s = new Stack(5);
            s.Push(5);
            s.Push(6);
            s.Push("string");
            s.Push(8);
            s.Push("ram");
            s.Push(8);
            s.Push(8);

            Console.WriteLine("Peek: {0}", s.TopElement());
            Console.WriteLine("Pop: {0}", s.Pop());
            Console.WriteLine("Peek: {0}", s.TopElement());
            Console.WriteLine("pop: {0}", s.Pop());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

You can modify above program as you see fit.

Comment: This is a pretty poor implementation.  It should be generic, rather than using `object` for everything, it's generally expected for such a structure to dynamically expand itself when full, rather than doing nothing, when there is a problem you should throw an exception, not write to the Console (what if the user of this class doesn't want the user to see that message, or what if they aren't using a console based application?), your peek method can throw index out of bounds errors, and it shouldn't return `0` if the stack has an empty array, it should throw an exception.